# can cudaMemcpy accept variables from device as its argument?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

```
cudaMemcpy(dst, src, filesize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

Where `filesize` is a variable stored in device global memory.

Comment: `filesize` is a `size_t` which is not a pointer. The value is read from the stack (host memory) so I guess it's not possible through *this* API. (Maybe not possible at all)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer is no.

The argument is passed by value, meaning the value must be known in the host code. Therefore you should have a first call to cudaMemcpy() to get the size and a second call to cudaMemcpy() to perform the actual copy.

If you're using Thrust vectors you can just read the element in the host code, but that's because Thrust handles the copy for you.